# Dog black stool, negative on tests

Tags: dogs, health

my 1 year old female 75 lb doberman, sharpei, Staffordshire terrier mix has been having black stool a few times a week.  It's solid in firmness, but pure black.  Sometimes mixed in with the brown sections.  Ran a preliminary parasite test on a black sample at VCA, was negative.  Ran a more comprehensive sample through a lab via my regular vet, which included test for occult blood, all returned negative on a pure black sample.  Just got these most recent tests back today, can anybody provide ideas about what might be going on?  First suggestions might be to try a different food, she's on Taste of the Wild Salmon, she was on the lamb flavor before.  She was on glucosamine chondroitin for hip dysplasia but I took her off that because I believe it increased the frequency of the black occurrence.  Also takes fish oil with her meals. Chews knuckle bones, elk antlers, and a Greenie dental chew per day.

Comment: My dog's fæces vary greatly in colour and texture, depending on what she has been fed: I notice they're darkest (indeed, pretty much black) when she has had some green tripe.  I've stopped worrying too much about fæces; and take note only if they're very loose for more than a day or if accompanied by other signs, such as a change in behaviour.